# Installing project from GitHub may create files I don't want to include in a Pull Request

Tags: git, github

I would like to contribute to an open source Python project on GitHub and have forked the project to my account, cloned it and added the original repo as described on GitHub.

In order to try the module out and play with it I will need to run `setup.py install`
But doesn't that change files in the package? I don't want those changes and any files that are generated, to be reflected in my next pull request.

Comment: This is a great question to ask on Programmers stack exchange which deals with issues around developing but is not targetted directly to questions about code itself.

Comment: @wheaties, I think it is a borderline question, but I find it suitable for SO, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> But doesn't that change files in the package?

If you setup a python package, the **source code** in the repo is **not changed**, but it might happen that new directories are added like `build`, `dist` or `package.egg-info` or the like. These should be [ignored](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) by the repositories' `.gitignore` anyway (and if not, that is probably a good first [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests)).

One thing, that can help with local development is to setup a virtual environment (with [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) while working and testing the package. With that you can setup and install (or even `python setup.py develop`) the package in an isolated, clean environment.